# Ложа и ложе

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Раз уж заговорили об однокоренных словах, то у меня тоже вопрос. Ложа — место в театре, ложе — кровать. Какая связь между этими словами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ложа в театре -заимствование из французского,оно ещё означало во фр. "беседка","хижина" -тот же корень, что и "луб, лубок" - пласт коры,тесина, доска - лубочный навес на столбах.Нем.Laube - беседка.

Ложе-кровать -от "лечь, ложиться" - место, где лежат, сюда же относится ложа-часть ружья.Однокоренные полог, ложбина

Comment: а не родственна ли франц. ложа с английским словом lounge? Очень уж похоже...

Comment: gecube, а "n"-то куда делась (или взялась)? Согласные просто так не пропадают. Да и значение далекое.

Comment: @behemothus, так французы вообще читают, что половина букв не произносится. Ну, и есть еще *англ.* lodge

Comment: Ну во-первых, мы об английском, а во-вторых, насколько могу судить при почти полном незнании  французского, написание французского слова (не только в данном случае) в целом передает именно историческую морфолигию.